# Android Studio emulator shuts down after launch

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-7, android-virtual-device

Android Studio installed a few days ago. First project. 
Worked fine, but after being in the background for a couple of days, the emulator was frozen. Had to force it down with Task Manager.

There was some message about "partially.." something. Then starting the emulator, it shut down after few seconds. Not even running an app. Just launching it fails.

Tried setting AVD (Nexus 5X API 26) graphics to software, no difference. 
Tried uninstalling/reinstalling Nexus 5X AVD, no difference. 
Tried uninstalling/reinstalling Android 8.0, no difference.

What to try next..?

Comment: The same was happening to me like a month ago. I searched everywhere no use. At last i had to reinstall the image and make a new AVD. Also try removing this folder's contents.  `C:\Users\name\.android\avd`

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the adb server by :-

adb kill-server
adb start-server

from your adb cmd prompt, I guess it should work.

Answer (score 0):

As of Android 3.4.1 update, you can solve these types of issues by right-clicking on the name of your virtual device and select "wipe data". Then run your device once complete. 
It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happened to me too. The solution is to update all the required components. To do that go to the "Tools" menu at the top in "Android Studio" and choose "SDK Manager". Click on "System Settings" in the left menu and go to "Android SDK".

1. Go to "SDK Tools" tab and see any update is required. If required update those by clicking the tick mark and pressing OK or whatever it requires.
2. Go to "SDK Platform" tab and tick the checkbox "Show Package Details". Then If you see any update is required/available then update those also.

After all that mentioned previously, restart "Android Studio" and try to run the emulator and it should work hopefully and not shut down after launch.